# iOS7 MDM NSUserDefaults downward compatibility

Tags: ios, objective-c, enterprise, mdm

I'm working on reworking an app to use iOS7's new MDM configuration with the settings coming from `NSUserDefaults` with the key `com.apple.configuration.managed`

My question is, will this work on iOS6 and below being it's a key in the defaults and not an actual API change? My guess is no, but I just want to verify.

Comment: "it's a key in the defaults and not an actual API change?" - The essence is to understand that it's not **just** a key in the user defaults. That's only the top of the iceberg. If it's not **implemented** in an older system, then you can add/remove/modify the key-value pair in the defaults, but it will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks, that's all i need to know

Comment: I am trying to make an existing iOS app able to be configured through MDM.  Similar to your question.  Can you point to a good resource that explains what's needed to do this?  Is it just adding NSUserDefaults then any MDM can configure it?